# Is it possible to execute a method (onInit method preferably) on fragment load (from another view) in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I want to execute onInit method on fragment load and add filter condition to the oData model. Its required to do so because I have to dynamically add the filter condition. Below is what I want to achieve.
`<Table id="mylist" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" growing="true" growingThreshold="10" growingScrollToLoad="true" width="auto" items="{path: '/element', top:10, filters : [{path : 'levelAggrId', operator : 'EQ', value1 : someDynamicVariable}]}" mode="MultiSelect" >`

If onInit() method gets called then I can move this filter in the controller. But onInit(). onBeforeRendering(), onAfterRendering() life hook methods are not getting executed on fragment load. Is it possible to do so using fragments or is there any other way to do so. Any pointers will be extremely helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment itself doesn't have a lifecycle method. But you can easily apply the filter in the controller and make the table busy for a short time. Every time the users fires an event to show that table, you can easily filter the table by getting the table via the id and then apply the filter function. 
Fragments are very good for dialogs but it seems that in your case using a fragment is not the best idea. The dialog has some events like 'beforeOpen'.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I used afterOpen() and applied my filter over there.